# Allowing users to selected resources in spring boot using jwt

Tags: spring, authentication, jwt

As titled, I'm trying to let only "ROLE_ADMIN" on my app to have permission to create a tournament.

My user:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public long id;

private String username;

@Length(min = 2, max = 60)
private String password;

private String email;

private Long tsRegistration;

private Long tslLastLogin;

private Long bonusCredit;

private boolean enabled;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_intournament", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tournament_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
public List<Tournament> tournament;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Collection<Role> roles;



private boolean tokenExpired;
```

Role:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private Collection<ApplicationUser> users;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "roles_privileges",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Collection<Privilege> privileges;
```

and Privilege classes:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
private Collection<Role> roles;
```

I created a sample test user with admin privileges:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        if (alreadySetup)
            return;
        Privilege readPrivilege
                = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("READ_PRIVILEGE");
        Privilege writePrivilege
                = createPrivilegeIfNotFound("WRITE_PRIVILEGE");

        List<Privilege> adminPrivileges = Arrays.asList(
                readPrivilege, writePrivilege);
        createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_ADMIN", adminPrivileges);
        createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_USER", Arrays.asList(readPrivilege));

        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
        user.setUsername("Test");
        // user.setLastName("Test");
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("test"));
        user.setEmail("test@test.com");
        user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(adminRole));
        user.setEnabled(true);
        userRepository.save(user);

        alreadySetup = true;

    }
```

After that, on my `WebSecurity` I allow only users with `admin` role to perform the action.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/tournaments").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

I tried using `.hasRole("ADMIN")` or `hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")` but it does not work, as I get 403 forbidden message.

I manage to login using "Test" and "test" credentials through postman and retrieve the bearer token, which lets me access all the resources that require authentication, except for the one that requires the admin role.

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/tournaments/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```